# Pydantic is not applying the default value

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the following schema.  If I input (enabled or disabled) in 'location' then this works and validation works fine. If I put a random string it fails (which is the way it should work). The problem is that if 'location' is an empty string.  This still fails.  I would like for it to set the default value and pass validation. I have tried to add the validator function below and it is not even getting to this function. It is automatically getting

```
Input should be 'disabled' or 'enabled' [type=literal_error, input_value='', input_type=str]"
```

I have added the default value and it is still failing.  Any idea what I am missing?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator
from typing_extensions import Annotated, Literal

ENABLED_DISABLED = Literal["disabled", "enabled"]


class GlobalSchema(BaseModel):
    location: Annotated[ENABLED_DISABLED, Field(description="Location")] = "disabled"

    # @validator('location')
    # def validate_location(cls, value):
    #     if value not in ENABLED_DISABLED:
    #         raise ValueError(f'Invalid value for location. Must be one of: {", ".join(ENABLED_DISABLED)}')
    #     return value or "disabled"
```

Comment: Are you using pydantic v1 or v2?

Comment: I am using pydantic==2.6.3

Comment: Thanks, I updated my proposed solution to Pydantic >2.0

Comment: Yes I saw that.  Apparently the pre/before is not needed because that is the default in <2.  But not sure why my version is not working.

Comment: I think it is good to be explicit about the validation mode. I think the biggest issue with your proposed code is that you treat the Literal like a union / tuple. Instead you need to use `from typing import get_args` and `get_args(ENABLED_DISABLED)` to extract the values. But in this case you might be better off using an `Enum`. But there is no need to re-implement the validation, as I noted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the desired behavior can be achieved by using a `pre` or `before` validator for the field. This validator will be called before the internal validation of Pydantic, thus there is no need to re-implement the validation for the literal value. My proposed solution would look like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, field_validator
from typing_extensions import Annotated, Literal

ENABLED_DISABLED = Literal["disabled", "enabled"]


class GlobalSchema(BaseModel):
    location: Annotated[ENABLED_DISABLED, Field(description="Location")] = "disabled"

    @field_validator("location", mode="before")
    def validate_location(cls, value):
        if value == "":
            return cls.model_fields["location"].default
        
        return value

print(GlobalSchema(location=""))
```

Which prints:

```
location='disabled'
```

In case of an incorrect value it raises:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for GlobalSchema
location
  Input should be 'disabled' or 'enabled' [type=literal_error, input_value='foo', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/literal_error
```

I would recommend to read about validators again in the Pydantic docs: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As you want to have the ability to pass any value, you should replace `ENABLED_DISABLED` with the `str`. The reason why you can't even debug is that you should pass location value like this: `a = GlobalSchema(loacation="")`, this is due to the validator function returns one more value when you are not specifying the exact field. And least, you shouldn't raise the exception when the value not in your predefined list. So you get something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, field_validator
from typing_extensions import Annotated, Literal

ENABLED_DISABLED = Literal["disabled", "enabled"]


class GlobalSchema(BaseModel):
    location: Annotated[str, Field(description="Location")] = "disabled"

    @field_validator('location')
    def validate_location(cls, value):
        return "enabled" if value == "enabled" else "disabled"


print(GlobalSchema(location=""))
```

Comment: This proposed solution changes the validation behavior such that for example `GlobalSchema(location="sdkfjf")` does not raise a validation error anymore. The problem is in the validator, where the string is always set to `"disabled"`, when it is different the `"enabled"`.